# Using C++ DLLs in Node.js native Addon

Tags: c++, node.js, npm, gyp

I had a C++ Win32 DLL built in Release/Win32 in VS2005 and I was trying to load it into a C++ Node.js Addon using LoadLibrary. This was failing continuously.
Then when I manually changed the build configuration in VS2005 to generate x64 DLL, then it worked fine.
I didn't provide configuration in my binding.gyp file for addon so it was probably built in x64 by npm, as I am on 64Bit Windows.

**How to provide build configurations to my addon(in binding.gyp?), if I want npm to build it build in Win32 always?**

I didn't find it on Node.js addon tutorial.

This question seems to be related to following **unanswered** questions:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22526273/using-dll-in-c-addons/26012936#26012936

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22836593/dll-not-being-loaded-within-a-node-js-c-addon

Thanks in advance!

Comment: May be this is useful: https://code.google.com/p/gyp/wiki/GypUserDocumentation